# Spot my error in solving a linear system

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I almost always get the unit matrix if I try to get to an row reduced echelon form. I probably always make a mistake. Can you spot the error? What illegal operations could a beginner do while trying to solve a linear system?

\begin{array}{}
1 & 1 & 3 \\
-4 & -3 & -8 \\
-2 & -1 & -2 \\
1 & 2 & 7 \end{array}
2.
\begin{array}{}
1 & 1 & 3 \\
0 & 1 & 6 \\
0 & 1 & 4 \\
0 & -1 & -4  \end{array}
3.
\begin{array}{}
1 & 1 & 3 \\
0 & 1 & 6 \\
0 & 1 & 4 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \end{array}
4.

\begin{array}{}
1 & 1 & 3 \\
0 & 1 & 6 \\
0 & 0 & 2 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \end{array}

5.

\begin{array}{}
1 & 1 & 3 \\
0 & 1 & 6 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \end{array}

6.

\begin{array}{}
1 & 1 & 3 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \end{array}

7.

\begin{array}{}
1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \end{array}

8.

\begin{array}{}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \end{array}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the move from $1$ to $2$, you incorrectly obtained $6$ when you should have obtained 4: $4 \times R_1 + R_2 \to R_2 = 0\;\;1\;\; 4\;$

thus giving to identical rows, rows 2 & 3.

\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 3 \\
-4 & -3 & -8 \\
-2 & -1 & -2 \\
1 & 2 & 7 \end{pmatrix}
2.
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 3 \\
0 & 1 & 4 \\
0 & 1 & 4 \\
0 & -1 & -4  \end{pmatrix}
3. \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 3 \\
0 & 1 & 4 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}
4. \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 1 & 4 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}

Answer (score 1):

Your very first step on the very first row operation, unfortunately